# How to create keyboard shortcut to move to beginning and end of Microsoft Word for Mac Document?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, office365, osx-el-capitan

On my Macintosh El Capitan, most applications treat <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd> as move to beginning of document and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd> as move to end of the document.

How can I set up keyboard shortcuts in Microsoft Word for Mac v15.26 (Office 365) to have the same functionality to move to beginning and end of a Word document?

Answer (score 1):

For the keyboard shortcut to move to beginning of a document use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd>.

To move to end of a document, use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>.

[Keyboard shortcuts in Word 2016 for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-Word-2016-for-Mac-3256d48a-7967-475d-be81-a6e3e1284b25) has the complete list of shortcuts.

Comment: What do you do if your Macintosh bluetooth keyboard does not have `Home` or `End` is there a way to still type those keys?

Comment: The Office support page and the above answer (see "or ...") mention the alternatives to `Home` and `End` for a Mac keyboard that doesn't have them. Try `command`+`fn` with the appropriate arrow key.

Comment: Correct, the arrow keys with command and fn work, my comment was whether there is anyway to generate a Home or End key on a keyboard without those keys labeled?